# How to fix bundleconfig.json file to properly bundle ASP.NET project C# in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, bundle

I am deploying my WebForm to an IIS server and my CSS and formatting is not being applied.

After the project source code had been developed on 2 different computers we received an error that the `bundleconfig.json` file did not exist and we could not deploy. We created the `bundleconfig.json` file manually with contents found on a Microsoft.com but I think the contents are wrong or not formed properly.

The project will deploy to the IIS server, but it looks like none of the CSS and formatting is being applied.

I have tried updating the

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "~/content/site.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
          "~/content/site.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false    
  }
]
```

I really have no idea what I am doing trying to format this `bundleconfig.json` file.

Comment: Maybe you need to try to add the `"includeInProject": true` parameter as well, e.g. after the `inputFiles` parameter. For the file you posted, you need to add it twice.

Comment: I added that to both input files and no change. [
  {
    "outputFileName": "~/content/site.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "~/content/site.css"

    ],
    "includeInProject": true
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "~/JS/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "~/JS/site.js"
    ],
    "includeInProject": true,
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  }
    ]